# How to calculate days between two dates from different sheets where the emails from both sheets in row match?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, match, vlookup, days

I have 2 sheets in same workbook that have dates that I need to calculate the number of days between the two dates. There is a common identifier in both sheets rows being email. If there is 0 days between dates it should state 0 and a date is missing it should showing blank ""

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tigqy4hKFn0Q7c-3ICyI6WREnsIBFZ2oLO8CEcdxe8w/edit?usp=sharing

results: Sheet1!J:2
start date Sheet1!D:D
End date: Day_count!B:B
Matching identifier = email in Col1 on both sheets

What would be the best way to work this out without using a helper column

**Answer**
This works when the lookup isn't in Col1

```
={"Day count"; ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(DAYS(VLOOKUP(A2:A, {Days_count!B2:B, Days_count!C2:C}, 2, 0), D2:D)))}
```

Comment: how about some demo sheet? or you want just some abstract answer?

Comment: Demo sheet added

Comment: answer updated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
ARRAYFORMULA
IFNA
VLOOKUP
DAYS
```

---

### update:

```
={"Day count"; ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(DAYS(VLOOKUP(A2:A, Days_count!A2:B, 2, 0), D2:D)))}
```

[image]

Comment: To then switch this to index match to avoid the vlookup ordering issues,  I thought it would change to this ={"Day count"; ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(DAYS(index(A2:A,match(Days_count!A2:B,2), D2:D))))} but nothing is returned in Col K when I try. Do you know why this would be please?

Comment: @Stuart not sure what do you mean by "vlookup ordering issues" tho

Comment: Vlookup requires the lookup value to be in the first column which I do have in my test sheets but my live data doesn't has this unfortunately. So I am guessing index match is the way to do it in my case.

Comment: @Stuart you can just switch them. instead `Days_count!A2:B` it can be `{Days_count!B2:B, Days_count!A2:A}`

Comment: Thanks for help, but I am a little confused. I have tried a few ways to replicate what I think you are suggesting in sheet1 Col N & O

Comment: @Stuart if you want to switch A & B column don't forget to put them in array {} like: 

`={"Day count"; ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(DAYS(VLOOKUP(A2:A, {Days_count!B2:B, Days_count!A2:A}, 2, 0), D2:D)))}`

Comment: Thanks, I never new it was possible to use vlookup for something like this. Really useful formula, thank you